# Android App Bundle not generating in Android Studio

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to publish my Ionic Angular app to the Google Play Store via Android Studio, but I'm having trouble generating the Android App Bundle.

When I open the app in Android Studio, I go to `Build` > `Generate Signed Bundle / APK`

The below 3 screenshots show the values I've entered.

Screen One:

[image: first_screen]

Screen Two:

[image: second_screen]

Screen Three:

[image: third_screen]

But when I click `Finish`, no prompts, error messages, etc. display to say whether or not the bundle was created.

When I go to `android/app`, there's no `release` folder appearing.

Can someone please tell me why no error message is appearing if the folder isn't being created?

Comment: check for the build error in Build window

Comment: After I click Finish?

Comment: Yes when you click Finish gradle task initiate and you can see progress bar at bottom tab of Android Studio. If it does not show or finishes check your Build Tab besides LogCat

Comment: So after clicking Finish, a progress bar does appear in right-hand corner but only for a very brief moment, I don't think it goes to 100%. When I open Build, only thing appearing is `Project setup: successful`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem (it looks like yet another Android Studio bug).

I solved it by:

- deleting the release folder
- creating a NEW KeyStore and NEW Key

Then it worked fine!

Comment: Thanks, renaming the release folder worked for me!

Comment: Thanks, just deleting the release folder worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would still be necessary but as a reference for those who might still encounter the same issue, I'm sharing. I experienced the same issue. Instead of Generate Signed Bundle, I tried from the Build bundle but was was built was a debug version. What worked was, I selected in the key store path"Create New" (instead of choose existing)but used the same file name and password of my existing key. With this, an app bundle was generated and the notice informing the location of the file popped out with the release file in it.

Comment: Only "Create New" on Key store path indeed did the trick for me. Thx!

Comment: Be aware that choosing "Create New" will overwrite your current upload key.  If the Play Console already has your current upload key, you won't be able to submit your new bundles without requesting an upload key reset which can take a week or more to process.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the versionCode and the version name in your build gradle file:

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "*********"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1       // Change this to 2 or more
    versionName "1.0"  // Change this to 1.1 or more

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately still behaving the same way

Comment: I posted another answer

Answer (score 0):

After clicking finish in the lower right corner there should be this window:
[image: picture1]

after that open the event log and click locate and it should open the folder with the apk:
[image: picture2]

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I'm not getting any windows like you are for some reason.
In the tutorial I'm following, he's getting the same window pop-up as you, but I'm not getting any pop-up.
If I do something like clean or re-build the project, I get pop-ups & the event log is updated, but when I go through the steps I mention in my question, I don't get any pop-up message for some reason :/

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I changed my keystore path. 1st check open signed bundle option, and check your key store path.